# Can OpenModelica use 'Support for partial derivatives of functions'?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

It seems that openmodelica can support partial derivatives of function.
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/changeset/c2540331314f2213474d703ce6cc6f9d012a5148/OpenModelica

Test Code is below.

```
model PartFncTest
 
    function sinwave
        input Real x;
        output Real y;
    algorithm
        y := sin(x);    
    end sinwave;
    function coswave = der(sinwave,x);
    Real cosVal;
    equation
    cosVal  = coswave(10);
 
end PartFncTest;
```

The code can pass at the check model step.

```
[1] 14:24:58 Scripting Notification
Check of PartFncTest completed successfully.
Class PartFncTest has 1 equation(s) and 1 variable(s).
1 of these are trivial equation(s).
```

But on simulate step, I got a translation error.

```
[2] 14:27:19 Translation Error
[C:/dev/OM64bit/OMCompiler/Compiler/SimCode/SimCodeUtil.mo: 830:5-830:83]: Internal error Creation of Modelica functions failed.
```

Someone know what happen for this traslation error?

Comment: I think this is not supported yet. The package may pass the check, but `coswave` does not - at least on my machine. Tried with OpenModelica v1.22.1 on Windows and v1.22.3 in Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: Thank you for assisting with the testing. Maybe I should try other modelica's tool.